# Is it possible to upgrade from (Ubuntu) Jaunty to Karmic Koala without reinstalling everything?

Tags: ubuntu

I have a lot of software installed on my Jaunty system. But I have heard that by upgrading to Karmic Koala some of my performance problems with the ALT+TAB task switcher may go away. I don't know if this is correct but I'm willing to give it a try if there is some way to easily upgrade without a complete reinstall.

So, is it possible to upgrade to Koala without reinstalling all of my software and losing all of my system customizations?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the [recommended upgrade procedure](http://www.ubuntulinux.org/getubuntu/upgrading) should smoothly upgrade you, keeping any software that you installed through the package management system in-tact.  Just open up the Update Manger, and click the upgrade button.

You may need to rebuild software that you installed from source.  It is quite possible that some of it will still work fine, but be prepared to rebuild if necessary.  Do you still have the sources available?

Answer (score 1):

Of course! If you installed all this software via synatpics, apt-get or aptitude, you should be fine.

Comment: I had to build some software manually.

Comment: It's difficult to say whether you will have to reinstall manually build software. However, you won't loose your configurations because they ought to sit in your home directory that the upgrade process won't touch.